# How can I stop cycle "FOR" after mistake

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide

Here is my javascript code (in Selenium IDE, with newlines and indentation added for clarity): storeEval |

```
var input = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++)  {
    if(window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(input[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color') == 'rgb(204, 230, 255)') {
        testResult='passed';
    } else {
        testResult='failed';
    }
}
```

| testResult

I need to check color of all inputs. But Selenium Ide stores the result of test only from the last "INPUT". I'm sure there are errors in the middle of the test. Help please. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: if you mean you want to stop the for after 'failed' than write break; command...

Comment: I tried to write breake: {testResult = 'failed'; break;}}, but my testResult now is alway failed, even when all colors are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should modify:

- `testResult` is given a default value
- a `break` is added when the test fails in order to stop the `for` loop
- discriminate whether you are dealing with a radio, checkbox or other type of input

Here's your code updated:

```
var input = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
testResult = 'passed'; // <-- set a default value for 'testResult'
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var bgColor = window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(input[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color');
    var inputType = input[i].type;

    if (inputType === 'radio' || inputType === 'checkbox') {
        if (bgColor !== 'rgb(r, g, b)') { // change the value to the desired one
            testResult = 'failed';
            break; // <-- this is what you need to break the 'for' loop
        }
    }
    else {
        if (bgColor !== 'rgb(204, 230, 255)') {
            testResult = 'failed';
            break; // <-- this is what you need to break the 'for' loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: big thanks, but but it doesn't work. Now, my testResult is always "failed", even when all colors are right. If it helps, here is page: svyatoslav.biz/testlab/megaform.php

Comment: oh! it's works! But... on my page i have 1 <input type="radio">, so my test falls. Without this input, test works correctly. Maybe somebody know, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: P.S. my script with "{testResult = 'failed'; break;}}" works too)

Comment: See my edited answer. Basically, filter out the `input`s which type is `radio`.

Comment: How can I filter out the input which type is radio and checkbox? Like this: if(input[i].type !== 'radio' && input[i].type !== 'checkbox' &&      window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(input[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color') != 'rgb(204, 230, 255)') ?

Comment: and How can I check color of this inputs? (type=radio or checkbox)?

Comment: I updated again my answer. Note that you will have to define the "fail" color in the case of radio or checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var testResult = 'passed';
for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++)  {
  if(window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(input[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color') != 'rgb(204, 230, 255)') {
    testResult = 'failed';
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh! it's works! But... on my page i have 1 <input type="radio">, so my test falls. Without this input, test works correctly. Maybe somebody know, how can I solve this problem?